# Create Master/Detail with Combobox and DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, master-detail

I have a ComboBox with its elements loaded from a sqlserver table (groups).
I also have a DataGridView, linked to another table (users).

When I load the form, the combo is filled with groups, and the datagridview is filled with users (all the users)

**1)** I want to be able to select a group from the ComboBox (dropDownList), and then to refresh the DataGridView with the users that belong to that selected group...

**2)** And How can I show a join relation in the DataGridView? Let's say I want to show the groupName in the last column of the each user...

**PS:**

> I have an xsd Dataset created in my VS2008 project with its
>   corresponding tableAdapters generated
>   (groupTableAdapter, userTableAdapter)
>   and some sql-methods added to each
>   adapter

Comment: Update1: I researched more, and found the filter option... int selected = int.Parse(myCombo.SelectedValue.ToString()); userBindingSource1.Filter = "groupId = " + selected;

Comment: Update2: Although the filter works fine, I'd like to add users in the dataGridView which their corresponding selected groupId -from combo- and to keep the filtering also... any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Set up a BindingSource for both tables.

```
BindingSource bsGroup = new BindingSource();
BindingSource bsUser  = new BindingSource();
bsGroup.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables["Group"];
bsUser.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables["User"];
```

2) Set up your Combo and Grid DataSources.

```
MyCombo.DataSource    = bsGroup;
MyCombo.DisplayMember = "GroupName"; // whatever your ColumnName is
MyCombo.ValueMember   = "GroupID";
MyGrid.DataSource = bsUser;
```

3) Set up a SelectedIndexChanged event for the Combo and use it to change the filter on the bsUser bindingsource.

```
MyCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(MyCombo_SelectedIndexChanged);
private void MyCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // this will depend on what your column names are, obviously
    string filter = string.Format("GroupID = {0}", MyCombo.SelectedValue);
    bsUser.Filter = filter;
}
```

This worked fine... taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3fba63f0-f027-48e9-b9a5-4738c620a5fb/c-master-detail-using-combobox-and-datagridview-with-tableadapters).

(Yes, I posted this also on MSDN because I was in a hurry)

Comment: The MSDN link is http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3fba63f0-f027-48e9-b9a5-4738c620a5fb/c-master-detail-using-combobox-and-datagridview-with-tableadapters